# Move only newest file over from one server to the other

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to move only one file that is the newest created or edited from a directory to another folder on two different servers.  How would I only move the newest file from one directory to the next instead of all the files in the folder?

Here is the code I am using to move the file over.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("\\172.16.1.42\s$\SQLBackup\FWP", "\\172.16.1.22\F$\BackupRestore", True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be too hard to determine which file is the newest one.  A simple way to do this would be to retrieve information about all the files in a directory and then cycle through them to find the most recent.

You could do something like this:

```
Imports System.IO

Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\") ' Change this to match your directory
Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

Dim mostRecentFile As IO.FileInfo = Nothing
Dim mostRecentTimeStamp As DateTime = Nothing

DateTime.TryParse("01/01/1900 0:00:00", mostRecentTimeStamp) ' Set to early date

For Each dra In diar1 ' Cycle through each file in directory
        If File.GetLastAccessTime(dra.FullName) > mostRecentTimeStamp Then
            mostRecentTimeStamp = File.GetLastAccessTime(dra.FullName)
            mostRecentFile = dra
        End If
Next

Debug.Print(mostRecentFile.FullName) ' Will show you the result
' Use mostRecentFile.Copy to copy to new directory
```

Hopefully that solves your problem. If not, let me know.  There may be an issue about this routine detecting hidden files, so if you see something like that, post back here.  You will also want to add code to detect if no new file is found, for example.